# Determine secondary structure (per residue pair) from a protein contact map

Tags: proteins, protein-folding, protein-structure

Given a protein map contact map (which for this particular case is a matrix of all Ca-Ca atoms in protein [`1a3a`](http://www.rcsb.org/pdb/explore.do?structureId=1a3a) that are less than 8 Angstroms):

[image]

**Question:** For each contact, is there an *established heuristic* to determine what kind (alpha, beta, or tertiary) of contact this is?

**Observations:** The contacts along the diagonal +4 clearly belong to alpha-helices, but I'm struggling to find a way to identify the parallel and anti-parallel beta-sheets and to differentiate these from a long range tertiary contact.